# Como eu faço para passar uma lista de parâmetros para uma procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, struct, stored-procedures, procedure

Eu quero passar N parâmetros de N tipos para uma procedure dinamicamente.

Como eu consigo fazer isso?

Exemplo:
struct = (Aqui será montada a estrutura com vários parâmetros)

struct.id = 123
struct.nome='Marisa'
struct.data='2020-06-16'
.
.
.
Execute sp_execute procedure struct

Como passar? E na procedure, como identificar?

Comment: cria um tipo com valores iguais da sua structure, veja mais aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: açresesente o seu código e a linguagem. [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há algumas soluções, sendo que uma delas é utilizar [table-value parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). No artigo [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html), de Erland Sommarskog, você encontra o roteiro completo.

No banco de dados é necessário definir a estrutura do parâmetro, através do comando [CREATE TYPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions). O tipo de dados criado é então utilizado como parâmetro no procedimento.

É uma solução bem simples de utilizar.

Comment: Obrigado @José Diz pela dica. Acabei não usando tantos parâmetros agora no momento, mas preciso entender melhor o link que você me passou para o caso de precisar no futuro. Eu não sou DBA, sou apenas um desenvolvedor que está precisando dar uma de DBA no momento. :) Para mim o link ficou confuso. Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: @RobsonCabral As informações que te passei são para desenvolvedores. Você pode testar à parte, em ambiente de desenvolvimento, de modo a dominar o recurso de criar tipos de dados. A sugestão é que um _tamborete_ para testes.